# Blob URL to image

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob

How can I "save" this image?

`blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787`

found on: https://theta360.com/s/lE2in9qQDK6j2CcjPAQcvNhOi

I tried some script I found on SO which uses `canvas.toDataURL`

But I get an error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787

Javascript:

```
var url = "blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787"; // document.getElementById("img1").src; // 'img1' is the thumbnail - I had to put an id on it
var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function () {
    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    document.getElementById("dataurl").value = myImage;
}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="MyCanvas">This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas</canvas>
<input id="dataurl" name="dataurl" type="text" size="50" />
```

Comment: Try replacing `%3A` by `:`.

Comment: In any case you can save a URL by creating an `a` element, set its `download` attribute to `image.jpg`, its `href` attribute to that URL and then click on it (with `.click()`).

Comment: no that did not work... `<a href="blob:https://theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787" download="image.jpg">download blob image</a>` **Failed. No File

Comment: There do not appear to be any `<img>` elements at linked page having `src`  "blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787"? It is not possible to request an `objectURL` from another origin; see "Security and other considerations" at [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 4: Object URLs](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/31/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-4-object-urls/)

Comment: you can download a blob using my downloader script: https://github.com/rndme/download

Comment: @dandavis Does your script download an `objectURL` created by `URL.createObjectURL()` at a different origin than the origin the script is called from?

Comment: @guest271314: i don't see how an objectURL could be from a different origin, but it's worth a shot. a[download] used to not care about origins, and now it looks at CORS, but i again, don't see how domain would come into play here... blob urls are made by window, so they have to be "local"

Comment: @dandavis See _"The URL.createObjectURL() static method creates a DOMString containing an URL representing the object given in parameter. The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created. The new object URL represents the specified File object or Blob object."_ at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL ; https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/31/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-4-object-urls/ at "Security and other considerations"

Comment: @guest271314: exactly. given all that, how could the url come from a different domain? if OP is trying to just paste in a random url string from somewhere online, then no, that's never going to work...

Comment: @dandavis That is, if not mistaken, what OP was attempting to achieve. That is, visit the page, copy url of `objectURL`, try to download the url from a different origin.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to request a URL created by `URL.createObjectURL()` from a different origin. `objectURL` exists within the `window` that created it for the lifetime of the `document` that created it.

[`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

> The `URL.createObjectURL()` static method creates a `DOMString`
>   containing an URL representing the object given in parameter. The URL
>   lifetime is tied to the `document` in the window on which it was
>   created. The new object URL represents the specified `File` object or
>   `Blob` object.

Comment: very very interesting.. So the image is loaded into the browser cache and deleted when the page is unloaded. The images can not be accessed because of the domain security! - I have been wondering about how to serve images that are not cached for AGES. Very cool. What about the cache? Can the data be pulled out of the browser cache??

Comment: @FFish _"So the image is loaded into the browser cache and deleted when the page is unloaded. The images can not be accessed because of the domain security."_ Yes.

Comment: @FFish There do not appear to be any `<img>` elements at linked page which have `src` set to `blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787` ? Where did you locate the url listed at Question at the linked document?

Comment: @FFish Yes, though note, your solution does not reference original url described at OP `blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787` ? Could not locate that specific url when visited page?

Comment: Yeah could be. Looks like the blob's numeric part changes anyway, maybe there is some timestamp involved?

Comment: That is how `objectURL`s are defined. Each is unique. Where did you locate the `blob:` url at linked page?

Comment: Note that objectURL may survive until you hard-refresh the original Document (just closing the window or a simple refresh won't release it). Hence the need to call `revokeObjectURL` as soon as the objectURL is not needed anymore (generally when loaded).

Comment: @Kaiido `objectURL` would also survive at `blob:` url until that particular tab is closed, even where `URL.revokeObjectURL()` called and original `document` , `window` closed.

Comment: @guest271314 hum no. As soon as `revokeObjectURL` is called, the objectURL is released. You can't load it anymore. Of course, it won't clear the one already loaded (be it in `<img>` tag or new window).

Comment: @Kaiido _"Of course, it won't clear the one already loaded"_ Yes, this is case attempting to describe at previous comment

Comment: Ok, so the url doesn't survive, only the decoded data fetched in cache.

Comment: @Kaiido If `cache` is enabled. Though should not be listed at `chrome://blob-internals` after being revoked

Comment: no even if cache is disabled, it will still be in cache as long as you don't refresh the page. It's not the same cache as the Network one. So it's more as long as the DOMObject containing the data is not deleted. But it becomes chatty ;-)

Comment: If cache is disabled, what cache are you referring to? Reference to object at `document`? _"But it becomes chatty"_ Well,  describe what you are referring to; please illuminate fully.

Comment: yes, the js cache or DOM cache or whatever you call it. The one that makes every object defined in the page available until you delete it. The one GarbageCollector will clear. Maybe "memory" is better than cache to describe it. But the point is that you will still have the data avalbale, but not from the url created.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it. For the first case, you can't access the blob from the url anymore. But if you saved it in a variable (using xhr) or in a DOMElement (`<img>` in OP), then you can still access the **parsed** response of the original and now revoked URLObject. In the second case, if you didn't revoked the url, then you can still access the file through the url (that you may have stored in localStorage or copy/pasted) until you hard-refresh the original page. Closing it is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

I found how to get the image but this does not has anything to do with programming anymore.

Look in Chrome's cache with `chrome://cache/`and do a search for `equirectangular_web_optimized`

Comment: That is not same url described at OP `blob:https%3A//theta360.com/473c6400-b8e7-4c41-8f7a-90f03cbc8787` ? Could not locate url referenced at original Question at linked page? Where did you locate the `blob:` url at linked page?

Answer (score 0):

i did this way to get the props sizes of an BLOB Url (file.localDataUrl)

```
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = file.localDataUrl;

    img.onload = (a) => {
        console.log(a);
        console.log([a.path[0].width, a.path[0].height]);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = e => {
    const blob = xhr.response;
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'title/file_name';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
xhr.open('GET', imageURL);
xhr.send();
```

or

```
fetch('imageURL')
        .then(r => r.blob())
        .then(r => {
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(r);
            link.download = 'title/file_name';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        });
```