# Getting image data from blob url

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, blob, tesseract.js

I have image elements in my DOM that use blob URL in their src attribute.
Think like this:

```
 <img class="full-media opacity-transition slow open shown" width="432"
 height="432" alt="" draggable="true"
src="blob:https://web.telegram.org/1c037f99-5201-45de-937c-548da5706021">
```

What I want is to be able to do some ocr on this image , however fetching the full url or even without the blob gives me a 404. How can I get the image either as a file or any acceptable format for tesseract.recognize?

**EDIT**

I've gotten the blob object and converted it to base64 in order to use it with tesseract on the node server side.
This is what I tried so far:
client side:

```
let imgOcr='blob:https://web.telegram.org/aab754ff-1bec-40bc-b55f-e2b08bf59ccb';     
const blob = await fetch(imgOcr).then(res => res.blob());
        var xj = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xj.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/imgocr", true);
                  xj.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                  xj.send(blob);
                  xj.onreadystatechange = function () {  console.log(xj.responseText); }
```

server side:

```
// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var upperBound = '1gb';
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: upperBound}));
//test for image ocr
app.post('/imgocr',(req,res)=> {
    console.dir(req.body);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(req.body);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
    var base64String = reader.result;
    console.log('Base64 String - ', base64String);
 console.log("tEsseract startng");
          Tesseract.recognize(base64String,'eng',{
            logger:m =>console.log("PROGRESS: "+m)
         }).then(({ data:{text}})=>{
             console.log("tESS RES: "+text);
         })
        }
});
```

but I get this error and I don't understand what am I doing wrong here:

> cannot read as File:
> {"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000H\u0000H\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\u0004\u0003\u0003\u0004\u0003\u0003\u0004\u0004\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0006\n\u0007\u0006\u0006\u0006\u0006\r\t\n\b\n\u00\u001e.ߒ}h�v���S�F�f�tz\u001d�A���'֏\u0017o�>�>�jFis\u000e�C��<]�$�����\nm]�5#4���y\u0011x�:ő���K�.���]\u001a�e\u0010�#�H`b�U��U�#<����Q\u0007\u0001�x,S]\u0004�<�Ѩ�Q\u000f\u0005
> at readFile (/Users/user/node_modules/filereader/FileReader.js:266:15)
> at FileReader.self.readAsDataURL (/Users/user/node_modules/filereader/FileReader.js:292:7)
> at /Users/user/Desktop/nodeServer/app.js:24:12

Comment: You can use `puppeteer` to take the screenshot of that `img` element and save the screenshot on disk. Once you have the screenshot on disk, you can perform OCR on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blob URL to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534368/blob-url-to-image)

Comment: I can't since it's a chrome extension and I shouldn't scroll up and down or save files on the user's machine.

Comment: @umuur I tried it but it doesn't work since I'm sending the blob url to my nodejs server and then 'downloading' it but it gives the file not found error.

Comment: You need to fetch this URL in your content script e.g. fetch(url).then(r => r.blob()), then do URL.createObjectURL and send a message with the result to your background script, the background script does fetch(objectUrl).then(r => r.blob()).then(b => fetch(serverUrl, {method: 'POST', body: b}))